# Deleting many tables in one query with foreign keys

Tags: sqlite

I have a post table that is a foreign key with 3 tables.
I want if I delete post , all comments images and likes delete as well by `post_id`.

```
post table
post_id  text  images_id 
1         post    1

images table
images_id   image 
1             text
comments table
comments_id  comment  post_id
1             text        1
likes table
like_id  status post_id 
1          1      1
```

how can I do that in one query??

Comment: Read this: https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php

Comment: Even as it doesn't spell *drop*, I find the title of this question unsettling.

Comment: @greybeard  You're welcome to update/reword it to be less disturbing.